# SQLite save NSData and get it back

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, nsdata

I'm using sqlite in my program. To save NSData I'm using this:

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(addStmt, 5, somedata, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

And getting it back like this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(selectstmt, 4) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(selectstmt, 4)];
```

But when I'm trying to see data:

```
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

It's returning: `<84fa8801 0200>`

Please help me to convert it to real NSData..

Comment: What did you original data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure

`NSLog(@"%@", data);`

is just printing out the memory address of the `NSData` object.  I think you're looking for something like this:

```
NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
```

This will give you the data contained at the current row in the first cell as an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "real NSData"? NSData will always be binary data looking quite the way you posted when using it in a log statement.

To have a printable NSString again, you have do create a NSString using the [initWithData:] function:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```